# UIWebView loading but not displaying website (XCode 4, iOS SDK 4.3)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

i'm going to write an app including an UIWebView. So first I wanted to try it out by just simply loading an URL.

- Created the UIWebView in Interface Builder
- Hooked up to the code

  `@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;`

viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
if(!webView)
{
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
}

webView.delegate = self;

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]]; }
```

also I implemented the didFailLoadWithError and webViewDidFinishLoad delegate methods.
webViewDidFinishLoad is called and indicating that HTML has been loaded.

Problem is: Even though webViewDidFinishLoad is called, the UIWebView doesn't display the website. It's only showing white color. The scroll bars right and at the bottom are shown when the UIWebView is touched and dragged but not content is visible. Nowhere found anything. Seems quite strange..

**EDIT**
This screenshot shows the connections of the xib:

[Connections](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/9149/bildschirmfoto20110424u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.. I used synthesize in the following way:

```
@synthesize webView = _webView;
```

So it was necessary to call the UIWebView in the following way:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:...];
```

New to this naming convention which is why i'm not used to necessity of self

Answer (score 5):

If you hooked everything up in Interface Builder correctly, the following lines should not be needed:

```
if(!webView)
{
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
}

webView.delegate = self;
```

Try removing them and see what happens. Also, put an `NSLog(...)` in the `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` callback and see if it is output.

Comment: thank you. done that but not working. i also thought that it's not necessary but I wanted to try everything.
when debugging viewDidLoad, i saw that the webView is allocated with 0x0. That might be the mistake. But shouldn't it crash when sending loadRequest to an unallocated instance? (it doesn't crash)

Comment: also when I don't alloc and init the UIWebView in code, the delegate methods are not called.. which means it really is not alloced and inited as it should be?

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  I had those lines in my viewDidLoad method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the File's Owner connect to the webView you declared?

Besides, webViewDidFinishLoad does not mean the HTML was loaded!
Whatever the content is loaded successful, this method will be called.

Comment: thank you, thats what i meant. in this case it's HTML ;) yeah, connection seems fine

Comment: I guess, maybe, you could check applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, whether the view is added to window?